# How to Upload files in Parallel or Bulk from CSV to SharePoint in PnP PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell

I am seeking a solution to upload files to SharePoint in bulk using PowerShell PnP. As such, I have written the code below which reads row by row from CSV and uploads the files, which is taking longer. It is uploading only 3k files within an hour. I am looking for batch processing to upload at least 7 to 8k in an hour. I have included my code below.

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVPath -Filter '*.csv' | Foreach-Object {
    #Import CSV
    $CSVData = import-csv $_

    # Built Url & Connect to PnP
    
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sharePointUrl 
    
    $CSVData | Foreach-Object {
      
        $Row = $_
Add-PnPFile -Path $Row.SourcePath -Folder $InsertorUpdateAt -Values $MetadataValue
}
}
```

Comment: What is the network speed and disk speed you are using to write?  You can't upload faster than the hardware speeds.  Parallel will not solve a hardware limitation.

Comment: @jdweng Here is Disk speed.                                                                                                     Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       481.64 MB/s          8.3
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   3479.60 MB/s          9.3
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  3584.48 MB/s          9.3
> Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     0.266 ms          8.5
> Average Read Time with Random Writes         0.284 ms          8.8
> Total Run Time 00:00:05.17 .  Network Speed 5 MBPS

Comment: So calculate the time.  I do not know the sizes of the files.  5 MBPS is very slow (most networks these days are at least 100 MBPS).  The is bit rate so to get bytes divide by 10.  So rate is 500K Bytes/sec

Comment: You are making a lot of connections to SharePoint Online. Try moving the Connect-PnPOnline statement above your loop so it only runs once.